# Iterator[Something] to Iterator[Seq[Something]]

Tags: scala

I need to process a "big" file (something that does not fit in memory).

I want to batch-process the data. Let's say for the example that I want to insert them into a database. But since it is too big to fit in memory, it is too slow too to process elements one-by-one.

So I'l like to go from an `Iterator[Something]` to an `Iterator[Iterable[Something]]` to batch elements.

Starting with this:

```
CSVReader.open(new File("big_file"))
  .iteratorWithHeaders
  .map(Something.parse)
  .foreach(Jdbi.insertSomething)
```

I could do something dirty in the `foreach` statement with mutable sequences and flushes every *x* elements but I'm sure there is a smarter way to do this...

```
// Yuk... :-(
val buffer = ArrayBuffer[Something]()
CSVReader.open(new File("big_file"))
  .iteratorWithHeaders
  .map(Something.parse)
  .foreach {
     something =>
       buffer.append(something)
       if (buffer.size == 1000) {
         Jdbi.insertSomethings(buffer.toList)
         buffer.clear()
       }
   }
Jdbi.insertSomethings(buffer.toList)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your batches can have a fixed size (as in your example), the `grouped` method on Scala's `Iterator` does exactly what you want:

```
val iterator = Iterator.continually(1)

iterator.grouped(10000).foreach(xs => println(xs.size))
```

This will run in a constant amount of memory (not counting whatever text in stored by your terminal in memory, of course).

I'm not sure what your `iteratorWithHeaders` returns, but if it's a Java iterator, you can convert it to a Scala one like this:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters.

val myScalaIterator: Iterator[Int] = myJavaIterator.asScala
```

This will remain appropriately lazy.

Answer (score 2):

If I undestood correctly your problem, you can just use [Iterator.grouped](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.Iterator@grouped[B%3E:A](size:Int):Iterator.this.GroupedIterator[B]). So adapting a little bit your example:

```
val si: Iterator[Something] = CSVReader.open(new File("big_file"))
  .iteratorWithHeaders
  .map(Something.parse)

val gsi: GroupedIterator[Something] = si.grouped(1000)

gsi.foreach { slst: List[Something] =>
  Jdbi.insertSomethings(slst)
}
```